# The syntax of "have something done"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, diagramming

I'm trying to parse this sentence:

> I had to have my immune system completely wiped out with chemotherapy.

sbj: I
vrb: {had to} have
obj: my immune system

Is "completely wiped out with chemotheraphy" a participle phrase modifying system or is it a complement of "my immune system"?

Answer (score 1):

"had to" is much like the model verb "must", except it can be used in the past, and unlike a real modal, it does not invert in questions (*"Had you to have it done?").  The main verb is "have" which here is a causative taking the complement sentence "my immune system (be) completely wiped out with chemotherapy".  The understood "be" is deleted in this type of causative construction.

> [subj I] [tensed_modal had to] [VP [V have] [S my immune system (be) completely wiped out with chemotherapy]]

The sentence complement is a passive whose active form would be

> (someone) completely wipe out my immune system with chemotherapy

where "completely" is an adverb modifying "wipe out", which is a transitive particle verb with object "my immune system" and instrumental adverb "with chemotherapy".

I don't disagree with what @chaslyfromUK said in a previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The object of *had to* is the non-finite clause *have my immune system completely wiped out by chemotherapy*.

Within that clause, *completely wiped out by chemotherapy* is the complement of *have*, its direct object being *my immune system*.

*Have X Y* typically takes a past-participle for its complement Y, so here the complement is an adjectival phrase headed by the pp *wiped out*.

Answer (score 0):

It is a passive construction with an implied agent.

Active: Medics completely wiped out my immune system with chemotherapy.

Passive: My immune system was completely wiped out [by medics] with chemotherapy.

Active: I had to have medics completely  wipe out  my immune system with chemotherapy.

Passive: I had to have my immune system completely wiped out [by medics] with chemotherapy.

---

Replace 'with' with 'by' and 'chemotherapy' becomes the agent. Then the whole thing is much easier.

Active: Chemotherapy completely wiped out my immune system.

Passive: My immune system was completely wiped out by chemotherapy.

Active: I had to have chemotherapy completely  wipe out  my immune system.

Passive: I had to have my immune system completely wiped out by chemotherapy.